# How to test if dynamic variable is generic type void in Dart

Tags: dart

I have a scenario in dart where I have a generic type `T`, which may be `<void>` at runtime. I need to test if a `dynamic` variable I get back from a service is of that generic type.

However the following test using the `is` operator fails when `T` is `void`, and I'm struggling to understand why. Can anyone explain this, and suggest a way I can test for this?

```dart
void main() {
  test<void>();
}

void test<T>() {
    dynamic foo = 42;
    print('$foo is void: ${foo is T}');
}
```

> 42 is void: true

Answer (score 1):

`void` is a special type.  In Dart, `void` does not actually mean "no type" but instead means a type that cannot be used. (See [Dart 2: Legacy of the `void`](https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-2-legacy-of-the-void-e7afb5f44df0).)

`void` is considered to be a supertype of *all* types because you can always treat any value as `void` by simply discarding (or rather, not using) the value. `x is T` checks if `x` is a subtype of `T`, and therefore it will be `true` for all `x` when `T` is `void`.

You cannot test if a `dynamic` variable is of type `void`.  That doesn't really make sense.  You cannot construct an object of type `void`, so the *runtime type* of a variable can *never* be `void`.  `void` is a *static* (compile-time) notion.  If your service gave you back a value, then you got *something* back, not nothing.

Possibly if your service gives you back "nothing", it's returning `null`.  If so, you can check `x == null` (although it might be ambiguous if if `null` might be returned for other reasons).  For example:

```dart
void f() {}

dynamic g() {
  return f();
}

void main() {
  print(g() == null); // Prints: true
}
```